# Why does Idris give me Type mismatch error for the following code?

Tags: idris, dependent-type

I am a newbie trying to learn Idris and wanted to create a function `test` that returns a Vector whose type is parameterized by the function argument.

```
vecreplicate : (len : Nat) -> (x : elem) -> Vect len elem
vecreplicate Z     x = []
vecreplicate (S k) x = x :: vecreplicate k x

test : (k:Nat) -> Nat -> Vect k Int
test Z = vecreplicate Z (toIntegerNat Z)
test k = vecreplicate k (toIntegerNat k)
```

When I try to compile the code with Idris I get the following type error

```
Type mismatch between
    Vect len elem (Type of vecreplicate len x)
and
    Nat -> Vect 0 Int (Expected type)

Specifically:
    Type mismatch between
            Vect len
    and
            \uv => Nat -> uv
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test : (k:Nat) -> Nat -> Vect k Int` takes two arguments, but you only match on `k`. That's why the expected type is a lambda (`Nat -> Vect 0 Int`). Just drop one `Nat`: `test : (k : Nat) -> Vect k Int`.

Also, `toIntegerNat` returns `Integer` not `Int`. `:search Nat -> Int` returns `toIntNat`, so that's what you want to use there.